# How to scroll to a specific item in an antd list by id?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an antd list displayed on a page and certain actions elsewhere will cause an item in the list to be selected. I want the item to automatically scroll to it.  I can't figure it out.

The code that displays the list is below.

```
   <List
                            itemLayout="horizontal"
                            dataSource={courses}
                            className="hoverable-list"
                            bordered
                            renderItem={(item, index) => (
                                <List.Item bordered="true" className={currentCourse == item.course_code ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => setCurrentCourse(item.course_code)}>
                                    {/* <Tooltip placement="bottomLeft" title={item.description}> */}
                                    <List.Item.Meta
                                        id={item.course_code}
                                        title={item.course_code}
                                        description={item.course_name}
                                    />
                                    {/* </Tooltip> */}
                                </List.Item>
                            )}
                        />
```

I tried using a getElementByID and then scrolling it into view, but that didn't seem to do it.

```
    const scrollToItem = (itemId) => {
        const element = document.getElementById(itemId);
      
        if (element) {
          element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
      };

    const handleNodeClick = (nodeId) => {
        setCurrentCourse(nodeId);
        scrollToItem(nodeId);
    }
```

Comment: Well.. the scroll is working - some.  It's moving the page instead of just scrolling the list itself.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a scrollable container for the list. Scroll in the container rather than the HTML document

e.g.

```js
import { List } from 'antd';
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const data = [
  { id: '1', name: 'a' },
  { id: '2', name: 'b' },
  { id: '3', name: 'c' },
  { id: '4', name: 'd' },
  { id: '5', name: 'e' },
  { id: '6', name: 'f' },
  { id: '7', name: 'g' },
];

const scrollToItem = (itemId) => {
  const element = document.getElementById(itemId);

  if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
};

export const App = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    scrollToItem('3');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      id="scrollableDiv"
      style={{
        height: 200,
        overflow: 'auto',
        padding: '0 16px',
        border: '1px solid rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.35)',
      }}
    >
      <List
        dataSource={data}
        renderItem={(item) => (
          <List.Item id={item.id} key={item.id}>
            <List.Item.Meta
              title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.name}</a>}
            />
            <div>Content</div>
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fbxcyu?file=src%2FApp.tsx)